# Django + nginx -- Connection Timed out on HTTP GET?

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

I have a django web app running via gunicorn and nginx is serving as a reverse proxy.

The web app provides few API calls. One of the API call (let's say `GET /users`) is giving me a `Connection timed out` error. All other HTTP calls work fine always.

If i restart the Django/gunicorn process, `GET /users` works fine for a couple of hours and then starts giving same problem again.

`GET /users` is simply parsing query params and pushing some data into rabbitmq. It's not the issue with rabbitmq connection/channel, that i am positive.

Anyone has any idea what could be wrong?

I have tried all available solutions on stackoverflow (including modifying `proxy*` headers in nginx, changing gunicorn timing and what not.)

Comment: Does it even reach django view? If so, I would add some logging to processing of ``/users`` call. This way you can see how far it actually get before it "froze".

Comment: It does not. I thought some middleware might be messing with it. But the middle ware is same for all API calls. So it is not causing problem.

Comment: firstly, can you bypass nginx and hit gunicorn directly? that removes some moving parts. secondly, do you see the call progressively getting slower, or does it respond fast until it hangs? you might be leaking some resource, eventually running out. maybe check memory, rabbit connection pool etc